# Converting from list of one POJO to another

Tags: java, guava

I have a list of POJOs in Java that I need to convert to a list of POJOs of another type.  Both POJOs have two String fields.  Is there a better way of doing this than just iterating through the original list and adding new items to a resultant list?  I know that in Java 8 I can write a Function which implements the apply method but I am using Java 7.  Is there a more efficient way of doing this in Java 7?  Example code below

```
final List<Tracking> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (DJTracking djTracking : trackingInformation) {
    list.add(new Tracking(djTracking.getTrackingNumber(), djTracking.getTrackingUrl()));
}

return list;
```

Comment: `new ArrayList<>(Iterables.transform(trackingInformation, new Function<DJTracking, Tracking>(){ /* implement it */});` maybe

Comment: Is `DJTracking` a subtype of `Tracking`? If so, you wouldn't need to do anything other than add it to the list. Otherwise, I'm not sure there's much else you can do to simplify it. You could make a utility class `DJTrackingConverter` with two methods `Tracking convert(DJTracking);` and `List<Tracking> convertAll(Iterable<DJTracking>);` and then just call `return DJTrackingConverter.convertAll(trackingInformation);`

Comment: Cannot use Function as I am using java 7

Comment: DJTracking is not a subtype of Tracking

Comment: I think the classes which RC is referring to, are part of the Guava library and can be used in Java 7.

Comment: Keep in mind that RC's solution can be less efficient than creating a copy if the resulting list will be iterated multiple times, as iteration will instantiate new `Tracking` objects.

Comment: Using `Iterables.transform`, as suggested by @RC., isn't necessarily the easiest way to do it: it can be just as straightforward to do it "by hand", i.e. create a list, enhanced for loop over the source list, do the "logic" in the loop body and add element to the new list.

Comment: @shmosel that's not true: it *does* create a copy of the list (note the surrounding `new ArrayList<>(...)`), so iterating it multiple times won't create any new instances.

Comment: @AndyTurner, oops I missed that (and he missed an end parenthesis). In that case, it's not any more efficient and not much cleaner (at least in Java 7), as you pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to break that code you mentioned, I mean write a method in firstClass for converting it to the second one, this may does not improve the performance but is cleaner.

```
public Tracking convertToTracking(){
       return new Tracking(this.getTrackingNumber(), this.getTrackingUrl());
}
```

and in anywhere you want you can convert the list simply:

```
final List<Tracking> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (DJTracking djTracking : trackingInformation) {
    list.add(djTracking.convertToTracking());
}

return list;
```